# How to properly set Gravity Forms Consent Label Indent

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity, gravityforms

I'm working a form built using Gravity Forms that has consent input. The consent statement is quiet long and I put in in label (not description -because my boss wanted it to be inline with the checkbox-) so that when you view it on mobile, it would appear like this:
[Long consent preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSnbY.jpg)

I have tried to custom with this CSS

```
.gfield_consent_label{
      padding-left: 2em;
      text-indent: -1.5em;
}
```

Apparently it fixes the label indent, but it also affect the check icon of the checkbox. The check symbol is showing outside of the box [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGwWS.jpg)

Any idea or inputs will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, Gravity Forms handles this automatically for Checkbox fields.

[image: Checkbox]

Based on those styles (and changing the vertical alignment to top), here's a CSS snippet that will help.

```css
.gfield_consent_label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: calc(100% - 32px);
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Final result:

[image]